# Custom ordering is Sympy?

Tags: sympy

I want to rewrite Integral of `10x^7-xy+y/x+2x^5` as sum of integrals.
Something like

```
Int(10x^7-xy+y/x+2x^5) = Int(10x^7)-Int(xy)+Int(y/x)+Int(2x^5)
```

But sympy makes its own ordering and outputs

```
Int(10x^7-xy+y/x+2x^5) = Int(2x^5)+Int(10x^7)+Int(y/x)-Int(xy)
```

Where can I override this behaviour if Int is my own class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is deeply engraved into sympy and you won't be able to override it by making your own class of `Integral`.

From the [Sympy docs](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html#understanding-expression-trees):

> Finally, one last note. You may have noticed that the order we entered our expression and the order that it came out from `srepr` or in the graph were different [...] This because in SymPy, the arguments of the commutative operations `Add` and `Mul` are stored in an arbitrary (but consistent!) order, which is independent of the order inputted.

So, similar to a native python dictionary, the elements are in an arbitrary but consistent order. There is no easy way to change this.

Comment: Dictionary orders aren't even consistent. You can create the same dictionary in two different ways and have a different iteration for the two. But the same SymPy expressions should always use the same order, no matter how they are made.